# Unable to keystroke spaces (non-breaking space) in AppleScript

Tags: input, applescript, keystroke

I am desperately trying to figure out why spaces are not entered, when using keystroke in AppleScript.

For example

```
keystroke "hello world"
```

Will only enter "helloworld" in whatever field I have selected.

I know the correct syntax for using keystroke, and tells, and what not. I can keystroke one word phrases just fine. But whenever there is a space, it doesn't go through.

This includes spaces in string variables. So if ThePhrase = "hello world" and I put

```
keystroke ThePhrase
```

I would get "helloworld" again.

Recently updated to OSX Sierra.

Comment: I have never used that command, but concatenation may be the best solution: `set thePhrase to "hello" & space & "world"`

Comment: no issue on ElCapitain. I tried with TextEdit : keystroke " " enter a space and keystroke "this is a text" also keeps spaces. no issues

Comment: You need to show more code so we can help find the problem, which will have to do with context, cause it's still working fine for me in Sierra. I can keystroke a string with a space in a TextEdit doc np.